# Wrong EOL characters when after writing .txt

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, spring-batch

I use **spring-batch 2.1.8 release**. Depending if the batch is executed under windows or unix, there's a different EOL character. On unix, the file generated only has `CR` - on winsows, there are both `CRLF`.

I configured my writter chunk so that it encodes the output resource has a windows one, like so :

```
<property name="encoding" value="cp1252"/>
```

But no sir. Unix still generates with only `CR`. It's in the context of a j2ee classic app with spring, controllers and models. So I can write code after the batch is done, before prompting the file to download for the user.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more likely that the Unix system only generates `LF`?

Comment: Yes LFs are unix stuff. But is there anyway do generate a DOS version, with CRLF ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting the lineSeparator property of the writer (assuming you are using a FlatFileItemWriter). The [javadocs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemWriter.html#setLineSeparator%28java.lang.String%29) indicate it is using the System property line.separator for the default.